# How can I get the return value from an ajax event?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

This is my code :

```
var noSubTasks = $.post('/taskuri/getTheNumberOfSubtasks/', { projectID: projectIdRow, taskName :  result }, function(data2){
    var x = data2;
});
alert(x);
```

and the fire bug show me this error :

```
ReferenceError: x is not defined
error source line:
alert(x);
```

can anyone tell me why  ???  and How can I assign the data2 to a variable ?? Thx

Comment: you can't do that since ajax is asynchronous see the above link to see how it can be handled

Comment: I know, but there is no some kind of tricky method or something to handle this ? thx

Comment: **no there is not** (of course you can make a synchronous request - but that is not a solution)

Comment: @Chester - `alert` is executed before the the server responses, that's why `x` is not declared as `var x` hasn't been executed at that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ideea to solve this problem would be : 
To create a hidden input type

```
<input type="hidden" id ="noSubTask">
```

To assign the data2 to the input type value

```
var noSubTasks = $.post('/taskuri/getTheNumberOfSubtasks/', { projectID: projectIdRow, taskName :  result }, function(data2){
$("#noSubtask").val(data2);
});
```

after that to  get the value from the hidden input :

```
var getTheNumberOfSubtasks = $("#noSubtask").val();
alert(getTheNumberOfSubtasks );
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problems

#### Ajax

... calls are asynchronous. That means if you want to access a variable directly after executing an ajax request, you cannot be sure that the ajax request is finished. You could use a [callback function](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) to solve this problem.

#### Scoping

The exception is thrown, because `x` is not defined in your scope. If you would change the `var x = data2;` to `window.x = data2;` or just `x = data2;`, you should be able to access (/alert) it in global scope.

I would recommend you to read the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope), due to very good explenation of variable scoping.

---

### Solution

[...]

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/taskuri/getTheNumberOfSubtasks/', 
  data: { 
    projectID: projectIdRow, 
    taskname :  result 
  }, 
  done: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    EvaluateAjaxResponse(result);
  },
  fail: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // Errorhandling
  }
});
```

[...]

```
function EvaluateAjaxResponse(ajaxResponse) {
  alert(ajaxResponse);
  // Do whatever you want.
}
```

---

jQuery docs:

- [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: how is the asynchronous call of the ajax handled the alert will get executed before the ajax called is executed

Comment: this lines of code is between a loop, projectID, taskname are different. if I alert(x) , it returns wrong values.

Comment: still the same, it shows that error in the console

Comment: now I get rid of this error, but it returns me always zero or nothing , which is not good. My function returns me the value from the function mysql_num_rows().

Comment: I bet you get an error from your serverside script. Please check your `php` and `sql`!

Comment: Check my post with my code, if I alert(data2) between the $.post , it shows me the right result, thx

Comment: If you inspecting your network traffic *(e.g. with firebug or native developer tools of your browser)*, can you see your request with the correct response?